# java agent class not found exception

Tags: java, command-line, jar, javaagents

I have a directory structure "D:\workspace 2\project\lib" where I have all the files "AgentMain.java"(which I copied from src and placed it here to make it easier), "asm-all.3.3.jar", "myagent.jar". Now when I try to invoke my java program like this from command prompt

```
D:\workspace 2\project\lib>java -javaagent:myagent.jar -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. AgentMain.java
```

it gives me exception in thread main java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError AgentMain/java and says couldnot find the main class AgentMain.java

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to execute your source file (AgentMain.java) instead of the class.  Make sure you've compiled AgentMain with javac and then remove the `.java` file extension.

UPDATE based on discussion from the comments:
Since your AgentMain class is defined in a package called "main" once you compile your class, its corresponding class file must be in a directory called "main".

so if you're running from your "d:\workspace 2\project\lib" directory with the command you included, the compiled class needs to be in d:\workspace 2\project\lib\main\AgentMain.class

Comment: yes now i compiled the source file first and then ran it with java but the error still remains

Comment: can you post the exact command you're now running as well as the error the JVM gives you?

Comment: This is my command :java -javaagent:myagent.jar -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. AgentMain .....it says the same error that noclassdeffound and couldnot find the main class AgentMain

Comment: is AgentMain.class in your working directory and does it contain a main method?

Comment: yes everything that i mentionded is in working directory and it also contains main method

Comment: Does your AgentMain class declare a package?

Comment: That is the problem. Don't forget that the class file needs to be in a directory structure that matches its package (so AgentMain.class needs to be in a directory called "main").

Comment: but i also put that class file generated (AgentMain.class from bin) in current working directory.\so if i am in the working directory lib as i mentioned before...and my src java file is in "D:\workspace 2\project\src\main\AgentMain.java" what should i do now..

Comment: I added to my answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `.java` files, you need to compile them first with `javac` and then run the compiled code (`.class` files). In your example, you have to run

```
javac -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. AgentMain.java
```

and then

```
java -javaagent:myagent.jar -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. AgentMain
```

Comment: yes it was my mistake...but the result is still the same..even after i used the AgentMain class file

Answer (score 1):

You should be referencing the compiled .class file, not the .java file

Answer (score 1):

java does not interpret source files.

You have to compile AgentMain.java with `javac` first. Then you have to specify `AgentMain` on the command line instead of `AgentMain.java`.